# LCD and Serial Monitor Arduino?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I have a program which prints to the lcd screen, I was wondering if I can have it also print to the serial monitor at the same time.

I tried serial.begin, but just got errors.

Comment: "just got errors" isn't a useful description of a problem

Comment: @gre_gor But we know what OP wants program to do, and I answered below.

Comment: @R.Gadeev we are supposed to solve problems, not just write code for him.

Comment: I guess, you tried to use `Serial.begin` function to print to the serial monitor instead of `Serial.println` function. Am I right, user443?

Comment: If my answer was useful then accept it please.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need this solution:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8);

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print(); // print something
  Serial.println(); // print Serial
}
```